# Dynamic scoping questions in R

Tags: r, eval, dynamic-scope

I'm reading the AdvancedR by Hadley and am testing the following code on this [URL](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#scoping-issues)

```
subset2 = function(df, condition){
  condition_call = eval(substitute(condition),df )  

  df[condition_call,]
}

df = data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 2:11)

condition = 3

subset2(df, a < condition)
```

Then I got the following error message:

> Error in eval(substitute(condition), df) : object 'a' not found

I read the explanation as follows but don't quite understand:

> If eval() can’t find the variable inside the data frame (its second argument), it looks in the environment of subset2(). That’s obviously not what we want, so we need some way to tell eval() where to look if it can’t find the variables in the data frame.

In my opinion, while "eval(substitute(condition),df )", the variable they cannot find is condition, then why object "a" cannot be found?

On the other hand, why the following code won't make any error?

```
subset2 = function(df, condition){
  condition_call = eval(substitute(condition),df )  

  df[condition_call,]
}

df = data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 2:11)

y = 3

subset2(df, a < y)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This more stripped down example may make it easier for you to  see what's going on in Hadley's example. The first thing to note is that the symbol `condition` appears here in four different roles, each of which I've marked with a numbered comment.

```
                              ## Role of symbol `condition`

f <- function(condition) {    #1 -- formal argument
    a <- 100
    condition + a             #2 -- symbol bound to formal argument
}

condition <- 3                #3 -- symbol in global environment

f(condition = condition + a)  #4 -- supplied argument (on RHS)
## Error in f(condition = condition + a) (from #1) : object 'a' not found
```

The other important thing to understand is that symbols in supplied arguments (here the right hand side part  of `condition = condition + a` at `#4`) are searched for in the evaluation frame of the calling function. From [Section 4.3.3 Argument Evaluation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-evaluation) of the R Language Definition:

> One of the most important things to know about the evaluation of arguments to a function is that supplied arguments and default arguments are treated differently. The supplied arguments to a function are evaluated in the evaluation frame of the calling function. The default arguments to a function are evaluated in the evaluation frame of the function.

In the example above, the evaluation frame of the call to `f()` is the global environment, `.GlobalEnv`.

Taking this step by step, here is what happens when you call `(condition = condition + a)`. During function evaluation, R comes across the expression `condition + a` in the function body (at `#2`). It searches for values of `a` and `condition`, and finds a locally assigned symbol `a`. It finds that the symbol `condition` is bound to the formal argument named `condition` (at `#1`). The value of *that* formal argument, supplied during the function call, is `condition + a` (at `#4`).

As noted in the R Language Definition, the values of the symbols in the expression `condition + a` are searched for in the environment of the calling function, here the global environment. Since the global environment contains a variable named `condition` (assigned at `#3`) but no variable named `a`, it is unable to evaluate the expression `condition + a` (at `#4`), and fails with the error that you see.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you give some more explanations? In my own example, 'a' could be found in the data.frame df, and df is the first environment R should look for, then why cannot R find 'a'?

Comment: @Jason OK, I've added an explanation. What's possibly confusing you here (and in Hadley's example) is that the expression `condition + a` in effect appears and is evaluated in two different places. Where it appears and is evaluated inside the function body,  a matching symbol `a` is found. But when it is evaluated as the supplied value of the argument `condition=`, it searches for symbols in the `.GlobalEnv` and finds no matching symbol `a` there. Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you so much for helping me! Your example is very enlightening! I think the common thing of your code and mine is that they both reference variable **a** that is not defined in the globaenv(). There is one thing I still don't understand: why the name of variable matters here? If I change the global variable from "**condition**" to "**y**", then there is no error. See the edited question. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Jason In your second example, when doing `eval(substitute(condition),df )`, `a` is found in `df` and `y` is found in the global environment (after it is first searched for and not found in either `df` or the list of arguments). In the first example, when doing `eval(substitute(condition),df )`, `a` is found in `df` and `condition` is found in the list of supplied arguments. Its value there -- in the list of supplied arguments -- is `condition = condition + a`. In evaluating **that** expression, `condition` and `a` are both searched for in the global environment, but only `condition` is found.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I have a follow-up question regarding eval: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59584695/2416535 if you are interested.

Answer (score 2):

I want to add some details in case someone stumbles on this question. The problematic line is

```
condition_call = eval(substitute(condition),df )
```

- The **condition** object in substitute() function is a promise object, its expression slot is "a < condition" and substitute(condition) takes expression and returns a call object with expression as "a < condition".
- Then eval() function start to evaluate the "a < condition" in the df environment. Its target is finding both **a** and **condition**.

  - **a** is found in df successfully, **and this is not where the bug generated**.
  - Then R starts searching **condition** in df and cannot find it.
  - So R goes up to the execution environment of subset2, and finds condition in the execution environment.
  - The variable it finds is actually the promise object mentioned before with expression slot as "a < condition".
  - To evaluate this expression, R has to find **a** again, and now it cannot find a any more because it has passed the df environment. **This is the part that really generates the error.**

To summarize the problem here:

- R does find **a** in the df for once.
- The bug arises when R tries to look for **condition** and then R takes the promise object **condition** instead of the **4** assigned outside as the argument and tries to evaluate it.
- Then R runs into the problem:

  - it tries to evaluate "a < condition" and it cannot find **a** either in the execution environment of subset2() or global environment.

For my second example, R cannot find y in the execution environment and then finds y in the calling environment of subset2() as 4, generating no errors. In this case, the name of y is different from the promise object **condition** and R won't try to evaluate "a < y" and no bugs generated.