# eval: why does enclos = parent.frame() make a difference?

Tags: r, eval

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51699452/2416535), the following throws an error:

```
subset2 = function(df, condition) {
  condition_call = eval(substitute(condition),df )  
  df[condition_call,]
}

df = data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 2:11)
condition = 3

subset2(df, a < condition)
## Error in eval(substitute(condition), df) : object 'a' not found
```

Josh and Jason from the original question did a great job explaining why this is. What I don't get is why supplying the `enclos` argument to eval apparently fixes it.

```
subset3 = function(df, condition) {
  condition_call = eval(substitute(condition), envir = df, enclos = parent.frame())
  df[condition_call, ]
}

subset3(df, a < condition)
##   a b
## 1 1 2
## 2 2 3
```

I understand that skipping the function environment means R is no longer trying to evaluate the promise, and instead grabs the condition object from the global environment.

But I think supplying `enclos = parent.frame()` should not make a difference. From `?eval` on the enclos argument:

> Specifies the enclosure, i.e., where R looks for objects not found in envir.

But if not provided, it defaults to:

```
enclos = if(is.list(envir) || is.pairlist(envir)) parent.frame() else baseenv())
```

which, in my mind, should resolve to `parent.frame()` anyway, because surely, `df` satisfies the `is.list()` check.

This means that as long as some object `data` returns TRUE on `is.list()`, the behavior of `eval(expr, envir = data)` and `eval(expr, envir = data, enclos = parent.frame())` should be identical. But as evidenced by the above, it isn't.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:** Thanks to SmokeyShakers who pointed out the difference between default and user-supplied arguments regarding the time of evaluation. I think this is actually already expressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15505111/2416535

It might make sense to keep this one alive though, as it touches `eval()` specifically (the other does not), and it is not trivial to realize what the generalized question should be until one has the answer.

Comment: Is it because of where `parent.frame()` is evaluated? When supplied, it's evaluated in the environment you call from. When not supplied, it's evaluated in the function's internal environment.

Comment: @SmokeyShakers that makes perfect sense. If you happen to have a link to a place where this is described (more specific than "Hadley's book" or "R manuals"), I'd be happy to accept that as an answer. Alternatively, if this is a duplicate, I'm happy to close.

Comment: I 100% got it from Advanced R. I'll try and find the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, different parents.  In the example that doesn't work `parent.frame` is looking up from inside `eval` into the internal environment of `subset2`. In the working example, `parent.frame` is looking up from inside `subset3`, likely to your global where your df sits.

Example:

```
tester <- function() {
  print(parent.frame())
} 

tester() # Global

(function() {
  tester()
})() # Anonymous function's internal env
```

Answer (score 0):

IT is getting confused by the double use of `condition`.  Change one of them to `cond`:

```
cond <- 3
subset2(df, a < cond)
##   a b
## 1 1 2
## 2 2 3
```

Note that even though this works it won't work if you put `subset2` into a function since it will look into the global environment where `subset2` was defined rather than looking inside the `f` execution frame and `subset3` will be needed.

```
if (exists("cond")) rm(cond)
f <- function() {
  cond <- 3
  subset2(df, a < cond)
}
f() # error
```

Comment: That part I understood. When the `enclos = parent.frame()` is supplied, the `condition` inside the function env is skipped, eliminating confusion. What was confusing me was the behavior of the `enclos` argument in `eval`, specifically why one has to supply `parent.frame()` even though it is the default. But SmokeyShakers explained that.